# Getting 'UnsupportedFileException' when playing wav file from URL in Java

Tags: java, audio, wav

I have to play a .wav file from URL but getting `UnsupportedFileException`.

Below is the code.

```
public class LoopSound {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {

            @Override
            public boolean verify(String urlHostName, SSLSession session) {
                System.out.println("Warning: URL Host: " + urlHostName
                        + " vs. " + session.getPeerHost());
                return true;
            }
        };
        // Now you are telling the JRE to trust any https server.
        // If you know the URL that you are connecting to then this should
        // not be a problem
        try {
            trustAllHttpsCertificates();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Trustall" + e.getStackTrace());
        }
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
        URL url = new URL(
          "https://74.127.51.154/SiPbx/playback.php?access=subscriber&login=501%40mix&domain=mix.nms.mixnetworks.net&user=501&type=vmail&file=vm-20130109213353000125_netsapiens_com.wav&time=20130110170638&auth=de5dda39287604a88fc4b80c467e161d&submit=PLAY");
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.
          getAudioInputStream( url );
        clip.open(ais);
        clip.loop(0);
        javax.swing.JOptionPane.
          showMessageDialog(null, "Close to exit!");
      }

     private static void trustAllHttpsCertificates() throws Exception {

            // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains:

            javax.net.ssl.TrustManager[] trustAllCerts =

            new javax.net.ssl.TrustManager[1];

            javax.net.ssl.TrustManager tm = new TempTrustedManager();

            trustAllCerts[0] = tm;

            javax.net.ssl.SSLContext sc =

            javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, null);

            javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(

            sc.getSocketFactory());

        }
     public static class TempTrustedManager implements
        javax.net.ssl.TrustManager, javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager {
    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null;
    }

    public boolean isServerTrusted(
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isClientTrusted(
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs) {
        return true;
    }

    public void checkServerTrusted(
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
            throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
        return;
    }

    public void checkClientTrusted(
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
            throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
        return;
    }
}
```

Below is the exception getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input URL
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at LoopSound.main(LoopSound.java:35)
```

When I place the above URL in a browser's address bar, I'm able to download the file but I'm unable to play pro-grammatically. How can I solve this ?

***EDIT***

I changed the link to

```
https://74.127.51.154/SiPbx/playback.php?access=subscriber&login=501%40mix&domain=mix.nms.mixnetworks.net&user=501&type=vmail&file=vm-20130109213353000125_netsapiens_com.wav&time=20130110170638&auth=de5dda39287604a88fc4b80c467e161d&submit=PLAY
```

Now the above link is placed on the browser its downloading the file.

but when i execute the program getting new exception now.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format ULAW 8000.0 Hz, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame,  not supported.
    at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectDL.implOpen(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.implOpen(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.open(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.open(Unknown Source)
    at LoopSound.main(LoopSound.java:36)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How could we help? I get a login screen when calling the URL from browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below link helped me and I am able to play the wav file now.

[How to play wav file with format CCITT u-Law](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.lang.java.gui/ObHGnLs_YU0)

### Edit

As per Millimoose comments, I am pasting some of the code from the above link to help others.

I am changing format of the wav file from `CCITT U-Law to PCM_SIGNED` which is the exact wav format.

```
URL url = new URL(
                          "https://sssss/xxxxx/playback.php?access=subscriber&login=501%40mix&domain=mix.nms.mixnetworks.net&user=501&type=vmail&file=vm-20130109213243000082_mixnetworks_net.wav&time=20130110170638&auth=c43ff32546e126be9b895bbf225b2e75&submit=PLAY");
                 AudioInputStream fis =
                  AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
                 System.out.println("File AudioFormat: " + fis.getFormat());
                 AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
                  AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,fis);
                 AudioFormat af = ais.getFormat();
                 System.out.println("AudioFormat: " + af.toString());

                 int frameRate = (int)af.getFrameRate();
                 System.out.println("Frame Rate: " + frameRate);
                 int frameSize = af.getFrameSize();
                 System.out.println("Frame Size: " + frameSize);

                 SourceDataLine line = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(af);
                 line.addLineListener(new MyLineListener());

                 line.open(af);
                 int bufSize = line.getBufferSize();
                 System.out.println("Buffer Size: " + bufSize);

                 line.start();

                 byte[] data = new byte[bufSize];
                 int bytesRead;

                 while ((bytesRead = ais.read(data,0,data.length)) != -1)
                     line.write(data,0,bytesRead);

                 line.drain();
                 line.stop();
                 line.close();
```

Comment: That thread starts with wild mass guessing and it's not clear what the solution was. You should include *what* in it helped in your answer, and preferrably why it did.

Answer (score 2):

[WAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) is a container format (like a zip file is a container of many different files) so there is no actual WAV Audio format (LPCM is the most common).  In this case your WAV contains a format called "CCITT u-Law" which isn't widely supported (its used for Cisco VoIP phones).  I haven't seen a Java Library that can read it, but maybe knowing what to look for will help.

Comment: Could this help? http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/media/sound/UlawCodec.java.html

Comment: I should upvote, because without your explanation, i will not try for converting u-law format to exact format of wav file. Thanks dude.